# How use when(x){} when the values of x is continuous?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In **kotlin** the values in expression **when()** is only Int. ¿How put values continuous or similar in cases with condition **<**?

My code now:

```kotlin
when (zoomCamera.toInt()) {
    in 0 until zoom15 -> placeTinyMarker(reportPet)
    in zoom15 until zoom17 -> placeMarker(reportPet)
    else -> placePicassoMarker(reportPet)
}
```

It is similar to this. (My code byfore but is ugly):

```kotlin
if (zoomCamera < zoom15) {
    placeTinyMarker(reportPet)
} else if (zoomCamera < zoom19) {
    placeMarker(reportPet)
} else {
    placePicassoMarker(reportPet)
}
```

Comment: possible [duplicate] of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408411/how-use-whenx-when-the-values-of-x-is-continuous

Comment: What is this? I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution in Kotlin is fine, honestly. If you prefer to use '<' though, you can simply not pass an argument to when.

```
val cameraZoom = zoomCamera.toInt()

when {
  cameraZoom < zoom15 -> ...
  cameraZoom < zoom19 -> ...
  else -> ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when (x) {
  in 1..10 -> print("x is in the range")
  in validNumbers -> print("x is valid")
  !in 10..20 -> print("x is outside the range")
  else -> print("none of the above")
}
```

There is way in Kotlin to achieve this

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html